# Using formulas within SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a three column workbook with the following data:

Col A: Names
Col B: Numbers
Col C: Dates

I'm currently using the following formula to get the sum of numbers from e.g. all "John" within the month of January.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B; A:A; "John"; C:C; ">="&DATE(2012;1;1); C:C; "<"&DATE(2012;2;1))
```

Is there a more elegant way of finding the correct month.

I did try:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B; A:A;"John"; MONTH(C:C);1))
```

But that did not work.

Comment: define "more elegant", please...

Comment: SUMIFS will be more efficient than other formula alternatives like SUMPRODUCT (especially for large amounts of data) so I would stick with SUMIFS in your current format or with a helper column if need be - if you don't want a helper column, as such then with just 1st of the relevant month in D2 you could use this version =SUMIFS(B:B; A:A; "John"; C:C; ">="&D2; C:C; "<"&EOMONTH(D2,0)+1)

Comment: "More elegant" as in just checking for month instead of checking for between dates. Just a preference on my part. I'll survive the rangecheck if necessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A100)="John"),B1:B100,--(MONTH(C1:C100)=1))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I would like to know more about what the "--" means and when this formula is consideres less efficient as sumifs.

Comment: The -- coerces a boolean response, i.e. returns a list of all the hits that match "John" in cells A1:A100. I've not done any time trials on this, but as SUMPRODUCT is basically comparing and then multuiplying the content of multiple arrays it is less efficient overall than SUMIFS as it is checking a set criteria against a set range. However, it is more versatile. Have a look at the [excel hero blog](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/01/the-venerable-sumproduct.html) for some more detail on SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the elegancy thing, but you can add a new column **month** using this formula (format the number as `mm` if you like):

```
=DATE(YEAR(C2); MONTH(C2); 1)
```

or `=MONTH(C2)` to return the same number for different years

and to get the result:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B; A:A; "John"; D:D; "2012-01-01")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't use additional columns unless the formulas automatically gets copied when adding or inserting new rows. I have to assume that the users of the workbook doesn't remember doing this manually.